# Mocking a function in a jest environment file

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to share a server between all my tests, to do this I create the file *server-environment.js*

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node')
const supertest = require('supertest')

//A koa server
const { app, init } = require('../src/server')

class ServerEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context)
    this.testPath = context.testPath
  }

  async setup() {
    await init
    this.server = app.listen()
    this.api = supertest(this.server)
    this.global.api = this.api
  }

  async teardown() {
    this.server.close()
  }
}

module.exports = ServerEnvironment
```

The thing is that I want to mock some middleware that the servers routes use but I can't really find a way to do that. If I try to declare *jest.mock* anywhere in the file I get the error that jest isn't defined. If I mock the function in the actual test file the global wouldn't make use of it. Not sure if something like this would be possible to do with Jest?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and solved it by adding `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

jest.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        './test/setupMocks.js'
    ]
    ...
};
```

test/setupMocks.js

```js
jest.mock('path/to/api', () => global.api);
```